# Am I guaranteed to not be bitten by this ODR violation?

Tags: c++, templates, linker, one-definition-rule

I have a header file that declares a template with a static variable and also defines it:

```
/* my_header.hpp */
#ifndef MY_HEADER_HPP_
#define MY_HEADER_HPP_

#include <cstdio>

template<int n>
struct foo {
    static int bar;

    static void dump() { printf("%d\n", bar); }
};

template<int n>
int foo<n>::bar;

#endif // MY_HEADER_HPP_
```

This header is included both by `main.cpp` and a shared library `mylib`. In particular, `mylib_baz.hpp` just includes this template and declares a function that modifies a specialization of the template.

```
/* mylib_baz.hpp */
#ifndef MYLIB_BAZ_HPP_
#define MYLIB_BAZ_HPP_

#include "my_header.hpp"

typedef foo<123> mylib_foo;
void init_mylib_foo();

#endif // MYLIB_BAZ_HPP_
```

and

```
/* mylib_baz.cpp */
#include "mylib_baz.hpp"
void init_mylib_foo() {
    mylib_foo::bar = 123;
    mylib_foo::dump();
};
```

When I make `mylib.so` (containing `mylib_baz.o`), the symbol for `foo<123>::bar` is present and declared weak. However, the symbol for `foo<123>::bar` is declared weak also in my `main.o`:

```
/* main.cpp */
#include "my_header.hpp"
#include "mylib_baz.hpp"

int main() {
    foo<123>::bar = 456;
    foo<123>::dump(); /* outputs 456 */
    init_mylib_foo(); /* outputs 123 */
    foo<123>::dump(); /* outputs 123 -- is this guaranteed? */
}
```

It appears that I am violating one definition rule (`foo<123>::bar` defined both in `my_header.cpp` and `main.cpp`). However, both with g++ and clang the symbols are declared weak (or unique), so I am not getting bitten by this -- all accesses to `foo<123>::bar` modify the same object.

**Question 1:** Is this a coincidence (maybe ODR works differently for static members of templates?) or am I in fact guaranteed this behavior by the standard?

**Question 2:** How could I have predicted the behavior I'm observing? That is, what exactly makes the compiler declare symbol weak?

Comment: I think the standard says "It should not work" but your linker says "It is OK".  Violating the ODR is a bad idea — the code won't work everywhere. In C, there's a 'common extension' that allows multiple definitions to work (see [How do I use `extern` to share variables between source files in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files-in-c/) — the feature is really a property of the linker, and there's a decent chance your C and C++ compilers share the linker technology.)

Comment: Agreed! I'm also pretty sure this should not work, but I can't really put my finger on it why. In my case I could (and should!) have declared `bar` `extern` and only defined it in `mylib_baz.cpp`, solving this issue. But I'm really curious to dig deeper and see the rationale behind the behavior I'm observing.

Comment: "`foo<123>::bar` defined both in my_header.cpp and main.cpp"... What? I see it defined in one place which is neither of the ones you mentioned: `my_header.hpp`. That is one definition.

Comment: @Barry, The header is included in both .cpp files (through `mylib_baz.hpp`), which are then separately compiled. As a result, before linking, there is a definition in both .o files

Comment: The question is: if you change it in one compilation unit, do you always observe it in the other?

Answer (score 1):

There is no ODR violation. You have *one* definition of `bar`. It is here:

```
template<int n>
int foo<n>::bar; // <==
```

As `bar` is `static`, that indicates that there is *one* definition across all translation units. Even though `bar` will show up once in all of your object files (they need a symbol for it, after all), the linker will merge them together to be the one true definition of `bar`. You can see that:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -c mylib_baz.cpp -o mylib_baz.o
$ g++ -std=c++11 -c main.cpp -o main.o
$ g++ main.o mylib_baz.o -o a.out
```

Produces:

```
$ nm mylib_baz.o | c++filt | grep bar
0000000000000000 u foo<123>::bar
$ nm main.o | c++filt | grep bar
0000000000000000 u foo<123>::bar
$ nm a.out | c++filt | grep bar
0000000000601038 u foo<123>::bar
```

Where `u` indicates:

> "u"
>   The symbol is a unique global symbol.  This is a GNU extension to the standard set of ELF symbol bindings.  For such a symbol the dynamic linker will make sure that in the entire process there is just one symbol with this name and type in use.

Comment: `static` isn't what's responsible for this, exactly.  It's that `bar` is a member of a template and can be instantiated (and unified between translation units) along with that template.